# SQLite comparing two fields

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a three column in sqlite (ID, ONE, TWO, ID is my primary key).

my problem is, I want to check if my data in my column One of id=1 is 0 or 1.
if the data is equal to 0 it will display a toast message, and if the data is equal to 1 is will display another toast message.

how will I able to do it in android?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table ", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
               //assing values 
               String id = c.getString(0);
               String one = c.getString(1);
               String two = c.getString(2); 
        //Do something Here with values

            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();

Answer (score 0):

To read data from a database, you'd typically use the [query() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), but reading a single value is easier with the [longForQuery() helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

```java
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase(); // inside an SQLiteOpenHelper-derived class
try {
    long one = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,
                "SELECT one FROM MyTable WHERE id = 1", null);
    if (one == -1) {
        // id=1 not found
    } else if (one == 0) {
        // ...
    } else if (one == 1) {
        // ...
    }
} finally {
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: I want to put my query in DatabaseHelper while my condition is in other class. how will I call my query?

Comment: Then give the condition as a parameter. (And when you have a new question, you should ask a new question.)